# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when using third party library in storm toplogy

Tags: java, linux, apache-storm

I am creating a storm topology that uses a third party library MITIE in one of the bolts. Per the documentation MITIE has some required native libraries and jars that are required for it to run.

It comes packaged with an example java class and script (run.sh) to run it that looks like this:

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/MITIE/mitielib
 export CLASSPATH=/opt/MITIE/mitielib/javamitie.jar:.

 javac NerExample.java
 java NerExample
```

This works. I then modified my ~/.bashrc file to contain the two exports above so I can run the script without having to have these exports in there. I removed the export statements from the script and it also runs fine.

My thought is if I create these two exports in my ~/.bashrc, then when I run my storm topology it should be able to pick up the library directory and work also.

The problem is that for some reason it does not work when I run my storm topology. I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no javamitie in java.library.path
```

I have looked everywhere for an answer, and have tired using the surefire maven plugin in my pom.xml like so:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${basedir}/lib/mitielib</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how I can get Native Libraries to work within a java storm topology project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching all of the possible configurations for the storm.yaml file, there was one provided that I missed the first time around and was exactly what I needed to solve this. by adding:

```
  java.library.path: "/opt/MITIE/mitielib"
```

to storm.yaml and rebooting storm, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically if you put any jars inside the storm's `lib` directory it will be included in the clssspath. Another way could be packaging all the dependencies inside the jar that you are going to submit to the cluster.